# Help with Blog Content Roll Up - Content Query

Tags: content-query-web-part, blog

Experts,

I need to pick your brain as I am pretty new to SharePoint and I am stuck!

I have a blog and then I have our intranet homepage. I have added content rollup/content query and linked it to the blog so people can see our news(stories). I need one section that displays 1 row, 5 columns, with 5 stories. 
Similar to this:
[image]
I have set up an additional column so they select which column it goes in(Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday).

The issue I am facing is when I create another Monday article, I want/need it to replace the other Monday article. When I add another blog post for Monday, It will add it below my other Monday and take off Friday's post. See below:
[image]

I figure it has to do something with the sort by or group settings. Do I need to add another column and filter by that? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Or maybe I can add a filter...?

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to create 5 web parts. One for each day by filtering from the additional column that you have mentioned to determine the day of the week. In web part settings set the item limit to 1 and sort by created date descending and filter from the day column so that only the last post will be selected.

You might have to create a page layout with 5 columns to display these 5 web parts in the same row.

Comment: Thank you. I will give this a shot. Little bit more work but I think it will work!